# The fundamental theorem of calculus for piecewise continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm trying to understand the following:

> Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann-integrable, and suppose that it is piece-wise continuous with respect to $a=x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n = b$, i.e. continuous on $(x_i, x_{i+1})$.
> Let further $F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and for any $i$ and all $s \in (x_i, x_{i+1})$ differentiable with $F'(s) = f(s)$.
>
> Then $$\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = F(b) - F(a) $$.

The proof is left as an exercise, so just hints would be appreciated.

My guess was something like
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b f(x)\ dx & = \sum_{i=0}^n \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f(x)\ dx
\end{align*}
and then to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to each of the integrals on the RHS.

But then I got confused by the open intervals in the statement:
It seems to me, that $F$ is not an antiderivative of $f$ on $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$, since by our definition it would have to be differentiable on that interval - but we only assumed open intervals.

So then I thought that the following might be true, which would immediately imply the claim. We simply make the intervals smaller:
\begin{align*}
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f(x)\ dx 
= 
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} 
\int_{x_i+\epsilon}^{x_{i+1}-\epsilon} f(x)\ dx
= 
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} 
\big( F(x_{i+1} - \epsilon) - F(x_i + \epsilon) \big)
=
F(x_{i+1}) - F(x_i)
\end{align*}
The first equation uses that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$.
This in particular makes the interval smaller, so that $F$ is an antiderivative, and we apply the fundamental theorem.
For the last equality we use continuity of $F$.

Does this make sense?
I'm not sure if the first equality in the last equation holds, so might not be 100% true.

Comment: Looks good to me. The claim then follows since the sum telescopes leaving only $F(b) - F(a)$.